# How to call a sighned Applet which returns a value from GWT on button click

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, applet

I am trying to call an sighned applet on by GWT button click. I tried going through the gwtai method of creating an interface on client side then writing an Applet which implements the interface.Howevere I get a TargetInvokationException when I call the method on my onClick() event.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
screenCap.addListener(new ButtonListenerAdapter() {
public void onClick(Button button, EventObject e) {
String filePath = counterApplet.captureScreenShot(); (Throws exception here)
TextField filePathT = new TextField();
```

My Applet Interface :

```
import com.google.gwt.gwtai.applet.client.*;

@ImplementingClass(com.jpmorgan.rd.querymanager.applet.imageCaptureAppletImpl.class)
@Height("10")
@Width("10")
@Archive("GwtAI-Client.jar,GwtAI-Demo.jar")
public interface imageCaptureApplet extends Applet {
String captureScreenShot();
}
```

My applet implementation class :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class imageCaptureAppletImpl extends JApplet implements imageCaptureApplet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -511774647966368672L;

   public String captureScreenShot() {

String file;
// do something

return file;
}
```

And the full stack trace:

```
load: class com.amol.test.imageCaptureAppletImpl.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jpmorgan.rd.querymanager.server.imageCaptureAppletImpl.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://127.0.0.1:8888/com/amol/test/imageCaptureAppletImpl/class.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 9 more
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amol.test.imageCaptureAppletImpl.class
```

Any help around this is Appreciated.

I have also created a signed jar of my applet can you please suggest if there is a better way of calling this captureScreenShot() method from my GWT page on button click and getting a result back.

Also is JSNI a better way of doing this. If so can you show a example where a applet which passes a value back is called.

Many thanks in advanced.

PS: I used this page for the basis of my code on gwtai :

http://code.google.com/p/gwtai/wiki/GettingStarted

Thanks,

Amol

Answer (score 0):

GwtAI is using JSNI to communicate with the applet. So whether you are writing the JSNI code yourself or using this library will be the same. Can you post the full stacktrace of your error?

Comment: hi adrian, thanks for replying first. I investigated somemore and found out that I am getting a class not found exception in my java console which can be the reason. here is the error trace :

Comment: In the applet interface you are using the annotation @Archive("GwtAI-Client.jar,GwtAI-Demo.jar"). So the applet runtime is looking for these two jar files and wants to load the imageCaptureAppletImpl class from there. Make sure the class is in one of these jar files and accessible.

Comment: Hi Adrian I tried that, I included the jar which is created by JarLinker here. But the problem is it looks for com/amol/test/imageCaptureAppletImpl/class.class  rather than com/amol/test/imageCaptureAppletImpl.class and doesnt find it.